# Update statement in Spring Data Rest with @Query throws EntityRepresentationModel not found

Tags: java

I'm facing some strange issue with my latest project.

I am using hibernate and spring data jpa + controller out of the box coming from @RepositoryRestResource.

as it is mentioned in the Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

you can have delete and update methods when you annotate your method with @Query and @Modyfing.

Well, i want to have a custom query which is updating an entities by a parent Id.

For example if we have :

```
{
@Entity
User

@OneToMany
private Set<Book> books;

}
```

and as well the bookrepository:

```
{
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<BookEntity, Long>{

@Modifying
@Query(UPDATE books SET books.price=0 where user_id=:userId",nativeQuery=true)
void updateBookPriceByUserId(@Param("userId") Long Id)

}
```

}
have in mind that i have the other classes implemented, that above is a pseudo code for the relation.

i want to update them by the user id.

When i reach the endpoint through postman, with @Param long id it says:

> ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found! at
> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc

Any ideas, guys?

[image]

Comment: Are you querying the correct endpoint? How does your REST request look like? Can you check which endpoints are actually created by Spring? E.g. like this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.resource-discoverability

Comment: Yes, i am doing http://localhost:8080/search/updateBookPriceByUserId?id=1
this is the correct endpoint and is alive, the problem is that i get two errors.
Error for the HTTP request and the one for the EntityRepresentationModel not found.
Actually, the get is working and is executing the statement via Hibernate, but it's not good to do it like this and i do not understand why it doesnt accepts post methods.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone face this issue, you should send a get request and the query is being executed.

Comment: Could be better if you mark it as correct answer to help others know it easier.

Comment: I cannot mark my own answers as correct, but if anyone has this issue just to know that it cannot accept POST methods.
You can execute custom queries only with GET method.